# How to pass google Oauth2 access_token acquired by server side to initialize client side javascript library?

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-js-client

My application is running in servlet container. Oauth2 integration is done using google sheets java client. Now I want to fetch spreadsheet from browser. I already have access_token, developerKey and clientId. But as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs) gapi.client.init() method does not allow to set access_token. How to pass google Oauth2 access_token acquired by server side to initialize client side javascript library?

Comment: I assume it is safe to do this because the access_token is short lived?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the gapi client as normal then set the token using `gapi.auth.setToken`.

Found this little tidbit in the [JavaScript client library FAQ](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/help/faq)